# ng build --prod --aot --preserve-symlinks give Module not found for lazy load module from extenal link package

Tags: angular2-routing, angular2-aot

I am new to AOT build and angular2 deployments.

I am using Angular 2 with Node @ 6.11.0, NPM @ 4.6.1  and                              @Angular/CLI @ 1.4.2

I have two projects where one is the host application (UI-Host) and the other is the actual application(UI-Core). I link and package the UI code and link it inside the host application i.e.

```
cd frontEnd/UI-Core

call npm i 
call npm link .\src
```

and in host application:

```
cd UI-Host

call npm i
call npm link UI-Core

call npm run build:prod
```

package.json -> scripts has got the following entry:

```
"build:prod": "ng build --prod --aot --preserve-symlinks"
```

I am using a lazy loaded module in the UI which is running fine with ng build and throwing the error as shown in the attachment with --aot prod build.

[image]

I am not able to figure out what is wrong with my setup. Please find below the code i am using.

```
frontend/UI-Core:
----------------

ui-core.routing.ts
--------------------------
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'workflows',
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        loadChildren: './components/imported/admin/admin.module#AdminModule'
    },
    { path: 'login', component: LogonPageComponent },
    { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'login' }
];

export const CoreRouting = RouterModule.forChild(routes);


index.ts
--------
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CoreRouting
  ]
})
export class UICoreModule {
  static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: UICoreModule,
      providers: [
        AuthService,
        AuthGuard
      ]
    };
  }
}



Host application ( frontend/UI-Host)
----------------

app.module.ts
-------------
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CUSTOM_IMPORTS
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }

custom\custom.app.ts
----------------------
import { UICoreModule } from 'ui-core';

export const CUSTOM_IMPORTS: any[] = [
    UICoreModule.forRoot()
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try for this:

Here we did aot false , which will not check all the depecies during production. use following.

**ng build --prod --aot=false.**

Comment: thanks. is there any other option to build successfully with --aot enabled?

Comment: You have to resolve each and every things of your project, after that this will successfully done